# OpenShift : Build failed with 'Invalid Output reference'

Tags: build, configuration, yaml, openshift

I am creating a build configuration with the following YAML. Then, I trigger the build manually with `oc`. So, the following commands are run.

```sh
oc create -f mybuildconfig.yaml
oc start-build bc/ns-bc-myproject --wait
```

Build configuration YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    build: myproject
  name: ns-bc-myproject
  namespace: ns
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'ns-is-myproject:latest'
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    git:
      ref: dev_1.0
      uri: 'https://github.com/ns/myproject.git'
    type: Git
  strategy:
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: 'nodejs:10'
        namespace: openshift
    type: Source
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
```

The build never goes through; it keeps failing with the message as Invalid output reference. What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an [image stream](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-streams) in the namespace where your build config is pushing the image to.

Something like this will work for you:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    labels:
      application: ns-is-myproject
    name: ns-is-myproject
    namespace: ns-is-myproject
```